# Cannot save file to Blob Storage using PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-powershell

Xposted question..

I am setting up a script from Azure Batch Services and have it injected to Azure Data Factory using Custom Batch Service.

- From On-Prem (from my local computer): I can save the file to blob using "Set-AzureStorageBlobContent"  though PowerShell just fine. (Set-AzureStorageBlobContent is only for uploading files from local to Azure, not Azure to Azure)
- From Cloud Shell, I can run $data | export-CSV -path ($home + "/clouddrive/" + $SubName + "result.csv") –NoType

However, from Cloud Shell. but it won't let me save the CSV to my blob storage, this is the steps:

---

1. I use cd to go to the blob storage container, where all my file resides e.g. azure\storageaccount\blob\container\xxxx\
2. Within the very directory.....I ran: $data | export-csv .\result.csv -notype
3. I get this error:

Export-Csv : Cannot open file because the current provider (SHiPS\SHiPS) cannot open a file.

I know it must have to do with the way I specify the out-path of the CSV file, or is it just not possible to export a file directly from Cloud Shell to blob storage?

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to send a file directly from Cloud Shell to Azure Blob Storage then it is possible as illustrated in below screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]